# custom files related list component not reflecting new files upload

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, contentversion

I have a custom lightning component that displays further details from the contentVersion.
the customer requirement is to display both, the standard files related list and my custom cmp.
now, when the user uploads a file using the built-in file upload, the standard files related list refreshed and reflect the new upload but my cmp not.
Do I have any ability to listen to the standard files related list refresh event and refresh my cmp?

Comment: you have the ability to listen to the standard refresh with adding `<aura:handler event="force:refreshView" action="{!c.doRefresh}" />` to your markup. for more help please share your code

Comment: thank u @ItaiShmida but it does not seem to be working. I opened the lightning console -  but no event has shown after the new file has been uploaded , only action.